# Ubuntu server stuck on startx

Tags: server

this is the first time I open a topic in this forum.
So... I bought a dedicated server and i'm still trying to get access via Putty and Remote Desktop Connection (Windows 7) to work inside the server without terminal (i love terminal :P). Following some guides on the internet, I installed

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

and then I launch "startx" but...

(Pastebin cause I can't insert more than two links :P)

http://pastebin.com/kkLAsCEt

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `Xorg` config fails at the `GLX` module. This appears to be a system bug and as such can not really be fixed.

Secondly, why are you even trying to RDP into a server?! There are two problems with that:

- RDP is a Windows-only protocol. It's not really going to work with Ubuntu.
- Security. Need I say more?

You really should use SSH only. Set up a server and just use PuTTY everywhere. You say you like the terminal anyways...

Thirdly, why do you need a GUI on a server? That is a dangerous can of worms that can break a lot. `Ubuntu Server + GUI = *Kablooie!*`

Comment: The fact is that I'd like to work quickly with folders and I prefer GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around with a program called [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), which allows remote admin capability for a command line interface server from a browser with a nice GUI. and it's very easy to install and set up. Here's a good Webmin [installation guide.](http://crybit.com/webmin-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

You can also download [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which allows you to run a linux-like command shell on top of windows, and ssh into your server, although that would be terminal.

I have been told by all the pros though that you really should embrace terminal, especially if your running a server. If you still have to have a desktop GUI you could just install [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx), which is a remote desktop tool, and manage it that way.

Comment: @Kowak, you can try webmin here, http://webmin-demo.virtualmin.com/ , before installing to see if it's what your looking for. The username and password are both demo. there is a file manager under the others tab.